# Honda Odyssey (2002) proper troubleshooting of code p1751

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, obd-ii, odyssey

Code is accompanied by rough shifting when cold. If I drive hard when its cold it will go into limp mode. If I take it nice and easy until its good and hot it seems to shift fine.

I've been searching around and have some ideas on what to check for this code, but the stuff I found is general Honda/Acura information, not specific to this model and year.

What are the specific avenues of investigation for p1751 on a 2002 Odyssey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to verify the AT fluid level is OK. Fluid at operating temperature, shut the car off and check the level, if it’s not between the marks top it off. If it smells burnt replace it.

By the dipstick are the two (A/B) AT clutch pressure control solenoid connectors. Disconnect both and check resistance. Spec is 3-10 ohms. If it’s out of spec replace the solenoids. If it’s in spec, with the connectors disconnected run power and ground. If the solenoid doesn’t operate replace it.

Near the two radiator hoses is shift solenoid B perform the same tests. Spec is 12-25 ohms.

If you have a scope and an HDS or similar just hook into the power side of the circuit and do a currant ramp test. You can actuate the solenoids with the HDS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Ben, I got as far as the fluid and resistance check on the A/B solenoids (both a bit over 6 ohms) before posting this question. Will check that other solenoid and do the power tests also. Don't have an HDS but I can make do with manual testing.  How careful do I have to be with regards to applying power to the pins, can I fry it if I reverse the polarity or short across the pins?

Comment: @CameronRoberts yes it’s possible to damage them. Also you’d only want to tap either power or ground. Extended solenoid activation can damage them as well. If you need to, pull the solenoids in question so it’s easier to access the pins.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll try to find a spare connector with cut wires that fits, and if I can't do that I'll pull them and test.  I'm a bit worried about contaminating the transmission with the solenoid off...